# Java key value pair without using collections

Tags: java, collections

How would I manage key value pair as in HashMap without using Java Collections.

I found this (Pair class from Commons Lang)

```
Pair<String, String> keyValue = new ImmutablePair("key", "value");
```

Is this the only way to handle? Or are there other ways to handle?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How is the key going to be used? Why wouldn't you want to use Java's classes?

Comment: You can use a List of Pairs, then implement some lookup logic on the list.

Comment: You could write your own class, you could use some other pair-type class, you could use a `List<String>` or even a `String[]`... there are lots of ways to get two `String`s. It really depends on your needs.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Somebody just popped this question and I got curious. Thanks everyone else.

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you trying to use a map-like data structure or you just want pairs? Do you want to query for something by key?

Comment: Yes, I want map like data structure with key & value.

Comment: How does Commons Lang's `Pair` type satisfy that?

Comment: It doesn't. Well when you asked earlier, I wanted to see if you have anything for map-like structure.

Answer (score 4):

personally i wouldn't, i like the built-in collections just fine.

having said that...

- if you want something with better performance/smaller in-memory size, have a look at [trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/). they have map implementations that do away with the extra Entry (key-value pair) class. theyre especially good if your keys or values are primitives (say, ints)
- if you want something with better predictability (another performance aspect), have a look at [javolution](http://javolution.org/). their collections classes offer much better worst-case times (think what happens when you insert something into a standard collection and you just triggered a resize...)
- if youre looking for collections classes with more features, have a look at [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Answer (score 2):

Try Generics and create your own class if you don't like java collections:

```
public class Pair<K, V> {

    private K key;

    private V value;

    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair<String, String>("key", "value");
        System.out.println(pair.getKey());
        System.out.println(pair.getValue());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` is *not* a `Collection`, so use a `HashMap`.

Comment: Yes technically it is not under Collection. But generally it is taken as one, no?

Comment: @SaM wat are u saying!

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz which part you didn't understand? All I'm saying is, if you look at collection chart, Map doesn't come under collection, but when you talk about Collection, Map is part of it. Am I wrong?

Comment: If map is not part of Collection then howcome You can talk about Map in collection

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz Although Map is not a Collection, it is part of the "Collections Framework"

Comment: @sam Although Map is not a Collection, it is part of the "Collections Framework"